# `require': cannot load such file -- ./controllers/<controller> (LoadError) with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, automated-tests

I'm trying to run a test file for a controller, but I'm running into this error:

> /home/mariana/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./controllers/users_controller
>   (LoadError)

I think rspec can't find the actual files it's supposed to test.

The test file, `users_controller_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require './controllers/users_controller'

describe UsersController do
  describe '#create' do
      ...
  end
end
```

The header/preamble of `rails_helper.rb`, that deals with file paths (I think):

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
```

The section of the Gemfile that deals with rspec and development/test-specific stuff:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'rspec', '~>3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~>3.5' 
end
```

The project tree:

```
   ->project
      ->app
        ->controllers
          ->users_controller.rb
      ->spec
        ->controllers
          ->users_controller_spec.rb
        ->rails_helper.rb
        ->spec_helper.rb
```

I've tried messing around with the `require File.expand_path(...)` line on `rails_helper.rb`. I also tried adding the `rspec` gem to the Gemfile alongside `rspec-rails` (the problem also existed when it was just `rspec-rails`).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by changing the path of the controller in the test from this:

`require './controllers/users_controller.rb'`

To this:

`require './app/controllers/users_controller.rb'`.

I already suspected it was a file path error, so I just tried different relative paths until one of them worked.